# WCF WsDualHttpBinding The caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, iis

I am attempting to implement a simple chat service using WCF (***WsDualHttpBinding***) so i can make use of the Callbacks.

My WCF service is hosted under IIS (8.5 I believe) under Arvixe shared hosting.

When I test my client and my service on my PC everything works like a charm. When I publish my service on Arvixe host and attempt to open a connection from the client app running on my pc (using visual studio) I get: "The caller was not authenticated by the service".

The service is hosted here:
http://www.4greatsoft.com/WebService/ChatSVC.svc

I can also get the service description with:
http://www.4greatsoft.com/WebService/ChatSVC.svc?wsdl

The firewall on the client PC is off.

**My service model configuration on the CLIENT (app.config) side is:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat" />
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://www.4greatsoft.com/WebService/ChatSVC.svc"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat"
            contract="IIS_ChatSVC.IChat" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat">
            <identity>
            <userPrincipalName value="PINE\4greatsoftcom_web" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**My service model configuration on the SERVER (web.config) side is:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsDualHttpBindingConfiguration" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsDualHttpBindingConfiguration" transactionFlow="true" >
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="ServiceAssembly.ChatService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsDualHttpBindingConfiguration" contract="ServiceAssembly.IChat" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Those service model configuration will yield a *"The caller was not authenticated by the service"* error.**

Following many suggestions on stackoverflow, I attempted to turn off security using the service model configuration bellow, but when doing so I get the following timeout error: ***"The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:09.7659996."***

**My service model configuration (causing timeout) on the CLIENT (app.config) side is:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:10"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
            <security mode="None">
                <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
            </security>
        </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://www.4greatsoft.com/WebService/ChatSVC.svc"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat"
            contract="IIS_ChatSVC.IChat" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IChat">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**My service model configuration (causing timeout) on the SERVER (web.config) side is:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsDualHttpBindingConfiguration" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsDualHttpBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                    openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:10"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="ServiceAssembly.ChatService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsDualHttpBindingConfiguration" contract="ServiceAssembly.IChat" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**IMPORTANT:**
please note that the use of "***WsDualHttpBinding***" is mandatory in my use case as I am using the CallBack feature of WCF. So NO I can't use "HttpBasicBinding".

To be brutally honest, I must admit that I am a total noob as far as networking security is concerned and I am clueless as to how to fix this. I have been on a "trial and error" binge for over 3 days trying all kinds of permutation to my service model configuration with no success...

That said, I would ask any would-be helper to be precise in there suggestion and not assume that I am a expert in the subject matter...

I believe this post ([WCF Client not able to negotiate security access with Service running in a different machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685095/wcf-client-not-able-to-negotiate-security-access-with-service-running-in-a-diffe)) comes close to explaining my problem but I still can't see what my solution must be.

At this point I am almost willing to contract a WCF/IIS expert to see this through if only I knew where to find one...

Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: This was my code base:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25261/A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application
I just used the code in a win-form app instead of the WPF app and I am hosting the service under IIS instead of the WPF Host. All of wich is essentially working properly.